# Not able to write multiple annotation images in itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, itext

Here i am trying to add to images as overlay on text.so i used pushbutton and annotations. but i can write only one image.not able to write second image onwards.Please help me

```
PdfReader reader1 = new PdfReader(Path);
FileStream fs = new FileStream(OutLocation, FileMode.Create,    FileAccess.Write,FileShare.None);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader1, fs);
PushbuttonField fld = new PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer,
    new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(315, 400, 210, 250), "Test ");
fld.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;
string Img = path + "RedSlash.png";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpeg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Img);
jpeg.ScaleToFit(100, 200);
fld.Image = jpeg;
stamper.AddAnnotation(fld.Field, 1);
fld1 = new PushbuttonField(stamper.Writer,
    new  iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(500, 500, 210, 250), "Test ");
fld1.Layout = PushbuttonField.LAYOUT_ICON_ONLY;        
iTextSharp.text.Image jpeg1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(Img);
jpeg1.ScaleToFit(100, 200);
fld1.Image = jpeg1;
stamper.AddAnnotation(fld1.Field, 1);
```

Comment: (1) I wouldn't use pushbuttons to add images on top of text. (2) if you do use form fields to do this, at least give different names to the different fields (now both pushbuttons are named `"Test "`).

Comment: Can you give me a code sample to add image on top of text?

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1 to your question was: make sure the different fields have different names. You fixed this based on my comment and it worked.

Answer 2 to your question is: don't use form fields to add images, just add the images "the normal way". You asked me for a code sample, I'm giving you a chapter of my book: [Working
 with existing PDFs](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). In this chapter, you'll find [some examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=6) involving the `PdfStamper` class. You can find the C# version of these examples here.

Some code:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, ms)) {
    Image img = Image.GetInstance(imagePath);
    img.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
    int n = reader.NumberOfPages;
    PdfContentByte foreground;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        foreground = stamper.GetOverContent(i);
        foreground.AddImage(img);
    }
}
```